# Unable to install homebrew in macos

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew

I am trying to install homebrew using command `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` on my mac but I am getting this error:
`HEAD is now at aa937b902 Merge pull request #11474 from cho-m/fix-tar-validation`.

I'm using zsh and already installed the Xcode using the command `xcode-select --install`

What can I do to solve the error? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest using `master` instead of `HEAD`.

Comment: Using `master` does not solve my problem.